# Reverse playback of a CATransform

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I have an animation created with Core Animation for my UIImageView, but i would like to know if its possible to play the animation in reverse/backwards mode. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715546/is-it-possible-to-play-a-path-backwards-in-a-cakeyframeanimation